# Photoshop CS 6 - Multiple shapes, same layer, different colors

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, vector, layers, shapes

Does anyone how I can change the color of a single shape, that is in the same layer of another shape, in Photoshop CS 6? The default behavior of changing colors seems to change the color of all shapes in that layer, as opposed to the selected shape only!

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "shapes" you mean vector layers or shape layers, then **no**.

It is not possible to have multiple colors on a single vector or shape layer. Any method to change colors will require at least one additional layer per color needed. That can be a separate layer for each shape, or a separate layer filled with color and masked - but it always takes additional layers.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely MUST only use a single layer, AND your shapes are spaced out, you could use a gradient fill on the shape layer.  With a bit of tinkering you should be able to achieve 1 layer and multiple colours.

However Photoshop is not designed to work this way.

If you don't know how to separate shapes into new layers it's easy: just select your shape with the Path Selector Tool (A) and use Cmd/Ctrl J to copy and paste to a new layer, or Cmd/Ctrl Shift J to cut and paste to a new layer.  Then in your layers palette you can click the layer icon to change the fill colour.